# Linux use interface for raw socket only

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

I'm having a OpenWrt Linux distribution for my embedded system. The device has 3 network interfaces: eth0, eth1 and wlan0.

One of the network interface (eth0) should be used for raw socket programming only. I'm able to create a socket with the parameters `AF_PACKET`, `SOCK_RAW`, `ETH_P_ALL`. The socket receives all network traffic, I can send packets and everything is OK.

But my problem is, that the OS is also using the interface for sending an reciving (e. g. ARP and ICMP requests/responses).

Is there any option that the interface is only used by my program and not by the OS itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible to achieve with a vanilla kernel. But this can come close:

First, ignore all arp requests on that interface:

```
echo 8 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/arp_ignore
```

Then, disable IPv6:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/disable_ipv6
```

Finally, filter all IPv4 packets coming on that interface

```
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
```

And do not set an IP-address or routes on that interface. This is of course not perfect, certain packets will still be processed by the kernel, but I don't think there is a much better solution.

Comment: OK. I have configured the firewall (iptables) so that every IPv4 packets getting dropped. But how can I disable ARP and IPv6 at start up. If I put the two lines you provided above in `rc.local` I always get a ICMPv6 packet (Router Solicitation) at boot up of the device. I think the commands in the file `rc.local` are executed too late. Any sugestions?

Comment: @BenjaminJ. Why is this a problem? You will always receive that packet, the important thing is, that the processing of that packet by the kernel doesn't hurt your application.

Comment: Sorry. I have expressed myself wrong. The packet is sent by the OpenWrt device. I have checked that via a Wireshark on Windows PC which is connected to eth0.

Comment: @BenjaminJ. you can try to disable ipv6 on the kernel commandline by appending `ipv6.disable=1`, but this will apply to the whole system then